# Android Root Detection is bypassed using Frida

Tags: android, android-security, frida

I have to prevent my native mobile application from getting bypassed from root detection using `FRIDA`. Currently I'm using `RootBeer` mechanism for root detection, which is getting bypassed by using the following command `$ frida -U -f com.am.app -l RootBypass.js --no-pause`.

```
[Google Pixel::com.am.app ]-> message: {'type': 'send', 'payload': 'Loaded 10653 classes!'} data: None
message: {'type': 'send', 'payload': 'loaded: -1'} data: None
message: {'type': 'send', 'payload': 'ProcessManager hook not loaded'} data: None
message: {'type': 'send', 'payload': 'Bypass root check for package: com.noshufou.android.su'} data: None
message: {'type': 'send', 'payload': 'Bypass root check for package: com.noshufou.android.su.elite'} data: None
message: {'type': 'send', 'payload': 'Bypass root check for package: eu.chainfire.supersu'} data: None
message: {'type': 'send', 'payload': 'Bypass root check for package: com.koushikdutta.superuser'} data: None
message: {'type': 'send', 'payload': 'Bypass root check for package: com.thirdparty.superuser'} data: None
message: {'type': 'send', 'payload': 'Bypass root check for package: com.yellowes.su'} data: None
message: {'type': 'send', 'payload': 'Bypass root check for package: com.topjohnwu.magisk'} data: None
message: {'type': 'send', 'payload': 'Bypass root check for package: com.koushikdutta.rommanager'} data: None
message: {'type': 'send', 'payload': 'Bypass root check for package: com.koushikdutta.rommanager.license'} data: None
message: {'type': 'send', 'payload': 'Bypass root check for package: com.dimonvideo.luckypatcher'} data: None
message: {'type': 'send', 'payload': 'Bypass root check for package: com.chelpus.lackypatch'} data: None
message: {'type': 'send', 'payload': 'Bypass root check for package: com.ramdroid.appquarantine'} data: None
message: {'type': 'send', 'payload': 'Bypass root check for package: com.ramdroid.appquarantinepro'} data: None
message: {'type': 'send', 'payload': 'Bypass root check for package: com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.COIN'} data: None
message: {'type': 'send', 'payload': 'Bypass return value for binary: su'} data: None
message: {'type': 'send', 'payload': 'Bypass return value for binary: su'} data: None
message: {'type': 'send', 'payload': 'Bypass return value for binary: su'} data: None
message: {'type': 'send', 'payload': 'Bypass return value for binary: su'} data: None
message: {'type': 'send', 'payload': 'Bypass return value for binary: su'} data: None
message: {'type': 'send', 'payload': 'Bypass return value for binary: su'} data: None
message: {'type': 'send', 'payload': 'Bypass return value for binary: su'} data: None
message: {'type': 'send', 'payload': 'Bypass return value for binary: su'} data: None
message: {'type': 'send', 'payload': 'Bypass return value for binary: su'} data: None
message: {'type': 'send', 'payload': 'Bypass return value for binary: su'} data: None
message: {'type': 'send', 'payload': 'Bypass return value for binary: su'} data: None
message: {'type': 'send', 'payload': 'Bypass return value for binary: su'} data: None
message: {'type': 'send', 'payload': 'Bypass return value for binary: su'} data: None
message: {'type': 'send', 'payload': 'Bypass return value for binary: su'} data: None
message: {'type': 'send', 'payload': 'Bypass return value for binary: su'} data: None
message: {'type': 'send', 'payload': 'Bypass return value for binary: su'} data: None
message: {'type': 'send', 'payload': 'Bypass return value for binary: su'} data: None
message: {'type': 'send', 'payload': 'Bypass return value for binary: su'} data: None
```

Comment: In the end everything you implement can be bypassed using Frida. So the only question is how hard the attacker will try too bypass your root detection. In general in the field of root detection and app hardening there is the simple rule that you get what you pay for. The more money you pay the harder it is usually to break the protection.

Comment: @Robert- is there any way to prevent the Frida script from injecting?

Comment: Search for "anti-debugging" and "anti-reversing" techniques, there quite a few but the mostly require detailed Linux knowledge and are implemented in C/C++. And because of the large number of different Android devices it costs a lot of money to maintain such frameworks as techniques that work on current Android version and devices may fail at any time with a new update, a new device or a new Android version.

Comment: @Robert - There is no proper solution explained anywhere regarding the use of restricting FRIDA/ FRID injection in android.

Comment: From app perspective Frida is a generic debugger so anti-debugging mechanisms are as far as I know effective against Frida.

Comment: @Robert- is there any proper documentation or source for implementing it to native android application?

Comment: If native=Java then no. As I wrote those techniques require compiled code e.g. c/C++.

Comment: @Robert - yea. I'm looking for native java code., which I don't find any solutions for it.

Comment: That is because Java does not contain the necessary commands.

Comment: @Robert - So there is no option for native android java application to be prevented from root bypass?

Comment: I am astonished RootBeer gained so much adoption. I remember when I first saw the library years ago and all the possible false positives. It's probably because OWASP heavily references it.

Answer (score 0):

As i can see your main issue is Frida
You can use several methods for detecting frida

Here is a GitHub Example Source For Detecting Frida

https://github.com/darvincisec/DetectFrida

This frida detection uses syscall so that it cant be hooked easily with frida

However it can still be bypassed if we hook some specific libc methods with frida. There is no permanent solution except detection

And if you are only trying to get a safe environment for your application you can use Play Integrity Check.